# normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

We define an algebraic extension $K/F$ to be normal if every irreducible $f \in F[x]$ with one root in $K$ splits in $K[x]$.

Now, in my lectures it was stated that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Why is this the case?

If one has an irreducible $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with a root $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$, then why does this imply that $f$ has all its roots in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Certainly we have $\alpha^*$ (the complex conjugate of $\alpha$) is also a root of $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, but how do we know we have all the roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Comment: An equivalent definition of a normal extension $K/F$ is one where $K$ is a splitting field of a polynomial $f\in F[X]$. Perhaps you could prove this equivalence, it should certainly be online somewhere. Then use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the splitting field of $X^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Hints: show that $\;f\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ irreducible with root in $\;\Bbb Q(i)\implies \deg f\le 2\;$ ...

Comment: DonAntonio: Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio You should make this an answer.